# How to prevent a 400 code being returned from java server side when you expect an empty result?

Tags: ajax, servlets

I have an ajax call to a server side java servlet and a null response is quite valid. However, I also get a 400 error code. The issue with this is that the 400 errors are filling up my report-uri log making it hard to find any 'real' errors. Is there a way to prevent the 400 code.

The ajax call is:

```
      $.ajax({
            url : 'NewsDispView',
            data : {
                ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
                ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                ssGroupID: sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupID'),
                ssGroupSection: sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupSection'),
            },
            type : 'POST',
            cache: false,
        })
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //      alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No News')){
                alert("No news");
            }else{
                alert("News");
            }
            var marquee = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'>";
            marquee += " No notices ";
            marquee += "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'>";
            $("#newsMarquee").empty();
            $('#newsMarquee').append(marquee);
        })
        .done(function(responseJson1a){
            // JSON response to populate the activities table
            dataType: "json";
    
            //alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson1a));
            
            //do stuff
        })
```

The servlet return is:

```
    if (newsList == null || newsList.isEmpty()) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "No News.");
    } else {
        String json = new Gson().toJson(newsList);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, why you `dataType: "json";` inside done function ?

Comment: Also , this `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "No News.");` is giving you 400 error ?

Comment: Yes, I am using json. Or are you saying the dataType should ne somewhere else? Yes, the newsList contains "[]", so "if (newsList == null || newsList.isEmpty())" is true.

Comment: You are sending that response know (400) from server ? Why not just send simple string or json to show `No News.` ?

Comment: @Swati Sorry I do not know what you mean. How should I adjust my code please?

Comment: Hi , simply generate json something like this `{"error" :"yourmessage"}` and then send that back to your frontend i.e : `String json = new Gson().toJson(yourjson);` and just check at your front end if the json has key `error` or not depending on this..change your ajax .done function logic.

Comment: Please add as answer.

Comment: Hi , you can answer your own question in detail :)

Comment: @Swati But then you do not get the reputation points. I think you deserve them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your error message as well in **JSON format** to your ajax call . So , generate your json then pass it like below :

```
if (newsList == null || newsList.isEmpty()) {
   String json = new Gson().toJson(yourjson);
 } else {
   String json = new Gson().toJson(newsList);
 }
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Then , check in your ajax code if the response has the key or not i.e : `error` and change your ajax logic accordingly.